# What is a TCP stream in a Nginx connection?

Tags: tcp

I'm working with Nginx and I'm searching what is a TCP stream. I haven't found relevant definition on the web, so please maybe someone has any answer to provide us ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446491/tcp-stream-vs-udp-message might be relevant.  TCP "streams" are just streams of TCP data - this isn't really an NGINX-specific question, and NGINX doesn't really have anything to do with a "tcp stream" other than being a piece of software that can interact with TCP data.

Comment: It depends on the context, but most likely in this case "TCP stream" is being used as a synonym for ["TCP connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156254/tcp-vs-udp-what-is-a-tcp-connection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally Nginx handles http or https connections. It now has tcp stream support. This means it can handle generic tcp protocols like DNS or smtp, etc. There are extra config parameters that need to be setup to enable this

https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html

also, concerning the TCP's support in NGINX, source here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/